# Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Mvc\ApplicationInterface' not found in C:\wamp64\www\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php on line 49 error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I did everything I can to solve this problem but I am stuck right now, all help is appreciated.

I am using Zend 2.4 with php 5.6. Yesterday before closing my PC everything was working really just fine but now it is not. I installed zend-skeleton application with composer. Any ideas?

Comment: check you autoloader portion (usually init_autoloader.php). my guess is that somehow "Zend" namespace is missing!

Comment: need more info here, did you install zf by composer ?